# Providing multiple result types with NSwag

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nswag

Is there any way to provide multiple `NSwag.Annotations.SwaggerResponse` types for the same status code in Asp.net WebApi (not core)? Actually, I have two response types, both descendants of the same abstract class.

I have tried to specify the base class as the response type, which results in having that class in the generated descriptor as the response model. Which is kinda normal.

I have tried to add two attribute instances with the two descendants. The resulting model is still the base class, not the actual class specified, but the descriptions are merged.

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(DeliveryData), Description = "Provided PIN code belongs to a delivery")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(AdhocData), Description = "Provided PIN code belongs to an adhoc visitor")]
```

The result is:
[image]

Interestingly, in the model list, I see both the base class and the two descendants.

Is there any way to instruct NSwag to generate alternate models ([oneOf](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/#anyof-oneof))?

Answer (score 0):

This page describes how to set up inheritance in the serializer and spec:

https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Inheritance

Comment: Well... looks to make no difference at all probably because it needs to be in a container class. Mines are directly returned.